# "Algorithmic ...ing..." vs "Algorithm ...ing"

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

Q: Question is general, but let's take some concrete examples:
Isn't

- "Algorithmic Auditing" - about audits done by (or using) algorithms (and  subject can be whatever)
- "Algorithm Auditing" - about audits (may be maid by humans) that subject of audit is algorithm

?

Background:

- "[Algorithmic trading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_trading)" - is when trading is done by (or using) algorithms
- "Algorithm trading" - isn't it trading (may be maid by humans) that subject of trade are algorithms ?

Now, let's generalise like in original question:

Isn't

- "Algorithmic Xing" - when X activity is done by (or using) algorithms
- "Algorithm Xing" - when X activity's subject are algorithms

?

### Source of my confusion:

I am asking you for confirmation of my understanding, as I am finding regularly uses of above constructs that seem like opposite to my understanding.

Let's take following example I came across recently:

> Title "Auditing Algorithms"
>   (...)
>   I’ve started a company (...) which stands for (...) and Algorithmic Auditing

in https://mathbabe.org/2016/07/22/auditing-algorithms/ at 2016-07-23

Also refers to :

> Algorithmic Auditing

in https://oneilrisk.com at 2016-07-23

It sounds to me like "Algorithms Auditing" not "Algorithmic Auditing".

Comment: You already have an answer. What exactly are you asking others?

Comment: @alwayslearning thank you for realising me, to make it bold that I am asking for confirmation of my understanding or showing what I miss. I know that despite general guidance about language it might have flexibility that might allow different application of mentioned structures, which might be to subtle to me as non native. Apart from this, I see misuses of "algorithmic", "algorithms", "algorithmican", etc regularily, so I seek for confirmation about proper uses. Again, dictionaries didn't help, as I am not aware if flexiblity in applied english is feasible or flagrant error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no contradiction between "auditing algorithms" and "algorithmic auditing", because it's the auditing algorithms that are doing the algorithmic auditing.

There is some ambiguity (as is common English) where "auditing algorithms" could either mean:

1. Algorithms that are used for auditing.
2. The process of auditing the algorithms (*i.e.* ensuring that the algorithms are correct).

The latter might be clearer if it were changed to "algorithm auditing".